# Compare two columns values using SQL

Tags: mysql

I have two columns in a table

- Column 1 has the value 'Migrated from A to B'
- Column 2 has the value 'A'

I need to do a search between these two columns to check if the value in Column2 ('A') exists in column 1 ('Migrated from A to B'). If it does then return 1 or 0 OR True or False.

Is this possible using SQL?

Your help will be appreciated.

Thanks
Sam

Comment: Please add sample data to your question, along with any query you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

Quickest and easiest is probably this:

```
case when column1 like '%'+column2+'%' then 1 else 0 end
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to use instr function to do what I was looking for and got the desired result

Instr(column1,column2) returns 0 if no match, returns position if match found.

Thanks.